# Ubuntu/Nginx - redirect external url to local folder

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have some files getting data from another domain not on my server. For instance pulling a pdf document from [www.example.com/mypdf.pdf](http://www.example.com/mypdf.pdf)
I have no control over this function, but instead of getting the pdf file from example.com, I want it to get the document from mydomain.com/mypdf.pdf instead.

Comment: That sounds like a XY problem. Please edit your question and add what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use
[Module ngx_http_rewrite_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)
and especially the
[return directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return).

Here’s a very simple example that redirects clients to a new domain name:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.old-name.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.new-name.com$request_uri;
}
```

The
[listen](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)
directives mean the `server{}` block applies to both HTTP and HTTPS.

The
[server_name](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name)
directive matches request URLs that have domain name `www.old‑name.com`.

The `return` directive tells NGINX to stop processing the request and
immediately send code `301` (Moved Permanently) and the specified rewritten
URL to the client.

The new URL uses two NGINX variables to capture from the original request
URL:

- `$scheme` is the protocol (http or https)
- `$request_uri` is the full URI including arguments.

For more information see
[Creating NGINX Rewrite Rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/).

Comment: this also works for outgoing links to external sites not on the server? thought listen only worked for incomming requests.

Comment: Your question relates to incoming requests. If the nginx server distributes requests to other servers, then this relates to those as well.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Harrymc, much appriciated as I still trying to learn all this server configuration stuff. Tried your code and no effect. I think the problem is that since example.com isn't located on this server, the listen function isn't picking up when the php script tries to get data from example.com. 
In windows I could do it by changing the host file to www.example.com 127.0. 0.1. I am looking for something similar here, but if possible, something that only affects mydomain.com on the server.  not sure it's even possible.

Comment: I don't understand - you can't modify a request that doesn't pass through your server.

Comment: Not even by doing some local dns lookup manipulation? So the script instead of getting the pdf document from externaldomain.com/mypdf.pdf, it gets it from myserver.com/mypdf.pdf ? I seem to recall doing something similar on an apache server a long time ago.

Comment: DNS could do that by attributing the IP of new-name to DNS requests asking about old-name.

Comment: Sounds like the way to go then.  Any tips on where I add this on a ubuntu/nginx server?

Comment: For DNS you need a local DNS server. Nginx is a web server and can't help. In addition, DNS can be complicated. See for example [How to install and configure DNS on Ubuntu](https://www.fosslinux.com/7631/how-to-install-and-configure-dns-on-ubuntu.htm).

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is basically a link.

You can create a link in your websites HTML which points to an external resource:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/mypdf.pdf">link text</a>
```

Comment: Yes a link, but I need to change the links target through server configuration. So if I add a link to https://www.example.com/mypdf.pdf, instead of going to https://www.example.com/mypdf.pdf I want to to go to mysite.com/mypdf.pdf instead..
Not sure if this can be done through nginx settings, beginning to doubt. But maybe some server dns lookup.